# Visual C# 2010 Cannot Open Setup Project Wizard

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, setup-project, wizard

I'm trying to create a Setup Project. I have opened my solution and the main project in my solution as per these instructions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx
I clicked File>Add>Add Project and it brought up the add new project window. But then the tut says to "in the Project Types pane, open the Other Project Types node, open Setup and Deployment Projects."
The problem is, I don't have a Project Types pane. Nor do I have anything saying Other Project Types or Setup and Deployment Projects. I have a pane with Recent Templates, Installed Templates and Online Templates in it, but that has no Other Project Types in it or anything of use. So I went to Online Templates. This looked promising, it had an other category. But there is nothing setup related in sight. So I used the search tool for Setup. Nothing. The tut says its for visual studio 2010. Do I need the non-express version? How can I get this wizard?

Thankyou,
YoshieMaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The express version does not come with all the whiz bangs of the full development suite, just the tools to develop apps, checkout the version comparisons [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison)

As as side, there's [this](http://dreamshield.codeplex.com/) solution on CodePlex, you could take that for a spin

Comment: Thanks, as I am a student, I just downloaded the full version off Microsoft Dreamspark